# Java: GregorianCalendar returns wrong data

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I want to calculate the monday of a specific week number of a year. This is how I do it:

```
final GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.GERMANY);
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012); // set to 2012
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 20); // set to week number 20
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin")); // set time zone

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy"); // german format
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime())); // return date
```

This has to return the 14th of May 2012 (14.05.12 in german format), but it returns the 16th of May 2012, but this is wrong.

So for 2012 its +2, 2011 is correct and 2010 is -1.

Why does the GregorianCalendar calculate the wrong date?

Thanks in advance and greets from germany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `DAY_OF_WEEK`, too:

```
final GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.GERMANY);
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012); // set to 2012
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 20); // set to week number 20
calendar.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY ); //set day to monday
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin")); // set time zone

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy"); // german format
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime())); // return date
```

Returns 14.05.12, 16.05.11 and 17.05.10 for me.

Edit:

> So for 2012 its +2, 2011 is correct and 2010 is -1.

If I understand that correctly, you get 16.05.10, 16.05.11 and 16.05.12, right?
That indicates that part of the calendar is reused. Did you, by any chance, test in a row starting with 2011? If so, changing the year only without any `clear()` etc. would keep the previously calculated date.

Comment: No improvement of the situation :( Thanks anyway.

Comment: With or without the extra line above, the result I am getting is _14.05.12_. Maybe there's code that is not provided in the snippet above or some config like Ashkan refers to.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that it makes sense to set DAY_OF_WEEK, before you set WEEK_OF_YEAR.

Comment: @Wivani yes I get the same result, too, since `DAY_OF_WEEK` will be monday by default, for the German locale. Something seems to be missing, maybe the calendar is reused etc.

Comment: Aww, sh*t! There was a mistake in how I set the year, in my "real" code I didn't use a constant, I used a variable and this was set to 2011. And - surprise! Monday of 20th week number in 2011 is - ding ding ding! It's the 16th of May. Thank y'all for your help anyway. This is so embarrassing ~.~

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on what getFirstDayOfWeek() returns and also what day the 1st of January falls on.

From Javadocs:

> Values calculated for the WEEK_OF_YEAR field range from 1 to 53. Week
>   1 for a year is the earliest seven day period starting on
>   getFirstDayOfWeek() that contains at least getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()
>   days from that year. It thus depends on the values of
>   getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(), getFirstDayOfWeek(), and the day of the
>   week of January 1. Weeks between week 1 of one year and week 1 of the
>   following year are numbered sequentially from 2 to 52 or 53 (as
>   needed).
>
> For example, January 1, 1998 was a Thursday. If getFirstDayOfWeek() is
>   MONDAY and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() is 4 (these are the values
>   reflecting ISO 8601 and many national standards), then week 1 of 1998
>   starts on December 29, 1997, and ends on January 4, 1998. If, however,
>   getFirstDayOfWeek() is SUNDAY, then week 1 of 1998 starts on January
>   4, 1998, and ends on January 10, 1998; the first three days of 1998
>   then are part of week 53 of 1997.

Comment: `calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.WEDNESDAY);` If you add this the result (in my Eclipse) effectively changes to _16.05.12_ (whereas it was _14.05.12_ before). Ashkan seems to be on to something ..

Comment: I added `calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);` and `calendar.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);` but they do not change anything. Both settings are now on german standard :(